# Installation of Google App Engine failed with SSLError

Tags: java, linux, bash, google-app-engine

While following the installation steps for Linux , at step 4 I used the below command to install the App engine

'curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com/ | bash'

During installation I choose JAVA as language. And, I got SSLERROR: read time out.

NOTE :- I install as 'su'.

### Environment

- Ubantu 14.1
- Java 1.7 update 67

### TRACE

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 260, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLError: The read operation timed out
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I am going through this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted. It seems the app enging java project follow maven. So, there is no need of installing app-enging SDK. Maven plugin for app-engine and the app-engine archetype will take care of the SDK and the project structure. You can find the app-engine repository [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/).

Thanks, this may help others.